# Rerender a panel in a simulation

Tags: java, image, swing, rendering

I am new to Java GUI and trying to build a simulator. In every step in the simulation I want to update a panel in the frame. This planel displays a BufferedImage read from a unique buffer created in every step in the simulation.

How can I update the image in every step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should draw it on its Graphics that was passed as parameter on paintComponent.(You should extends JPanel for it)

Every step, you generate the new image. And call repaint to your JPanel draw the new Content on its Graphics.

Comment: If you need hardware acceleration, or to draw off the EDT, look into Active Rendering and the AWT Canvas. http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/languages/java/java-games-active-rendering-r2418

Comment: You don't need to have a Canvas to do it. The Swing is already Hardware accelerated, and if you wont Flickering, you can use BufferStrategy.

Comment: Yeah, using lightweight Swing component is a far better idea.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Well the canvas lets you draw, AND show to the screen, in a separate thread.